# How to translate this code into python 3?

Tags: python-3.7

This code is originally written in Python 2 and I need to translate it in python 3!
I'm sorry for not sharing enough information:
Also, here's the part where `self.D` was first assigned:

```
    def __init__(self,instance,transformed,describe1,describe2):
        self.D=[]
        self.instance=instance
        self.transformed=transformed
        self.describe1,self.describe2=describe1,describe2
        self.describe=self.describe1+', '+self.describe2 if self.describe2 else self.describe1
        self.column_num=self.tuple_num=self.view_num=0
        self.names=[]
        self.types=[]
        self.origins=[]
        self.features=[]
        self.views=[]
        self.classify_id=-1
        self.classify_num = 1
        self.classes=[]


    def generateViews(self):
        T=map(list,zip(*self.D))
        if self.transformed==0:
            s= int( self.column_num)
            for column_id in range(s):
                f = Features(self.names[column_id],self.types[column_id],self.origins[column_id])

            #calculate min,max for numerical,temporal
                if f.type==Type.numerical or f.type==Type.temporal:
                   f.min,f.max=min(T[column_id]),max(T[column_id])
                   if f.min==f.max:
                      self.types[column_id]=f.type=Type.none
                      self.features.append(f)
                      continue

                d={}
            #calculate distinct,ratio for categorical,temporal
                if f.type == Type.categorical or f.type == Type.temporal:
                   for i in range(self.tuple_num):
                       print([type(self.D[i]) for i in range(self.tuple_num)])
                       if self.D[i][column_id] in d:                           
                          d[self.D[i][column_id]]+=1
                       else:
                          d[self.D[i][column_id]]=1
                    f.distinct = len(d)
                    f.ratio = 1.0 * f.distinct / self.tuple_num
                    f.distinct_values=[(k,d[k]) for k in sorted(d)]
                    if f.type==Type.temporal:
                       self.getIntervalBins(f)

                   self.features.append(f)
```

TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet you have given is not enough to solve the problem. The problem lies in `self.D` which you are trying to subscript using `self.D[i]`. Please look into your code where `self.D` is instantiated and make sure that its an array-like variable so that you can subscript it.

### Edit

based on your edit, please confirm that whether `self.D[i]` is also array-like for all `i` in the range mentioned in the code. you can do that by simply

```
print([type(self.D[i]) for i in range(self.tuple_num))
```

share the response of this code, so that I may help further.

### Edit-2

As per your comments and the edited code snippet, it seems that `self.D` is the output of some `map` function. In python 2, `map` is a function that returns a list. However, in python3 `map` is a class that when invoked, creates a map object.

The simplest way to resolve this is the find out the line where `self.D` was first assigned, and whatever code is in the RHS, wrap it with a `list(...)` function.

Alternately, just after this line

```
T=map(list,zip(*self.D))
```

add the following

```
self.D = list(self.D)
```

Hope this will resolve the issue

Comment: TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable. 
Does that mean `self.D` is a map object?

Comment: In that case, `self.D` is definitely not a list as you claimed. check `isinstance(self.D, list)` or simply put `type(self.D)` to check what type of variable it is

Comment: it prints `False`

Comment: which means your self.D is not a list. my bet is that it is a map object. I need more of your code in order to debug it completely.

Comment: I already edited my question, I hope I provided enough information now!

Comment: It still does not contain the part where `self.D` was first assigned. However, I got some idea regarding the issue. Give me 5 min, I am editing my answer

Answer (score 0):

We don't have quite enough information to answer the question, but in Python 3, generator and map objects are not subscriptable. I think it may be in your

```
self.D[i]
```

variable, because you claim that `self.D` is a list, but it is possible that `self.D[i]` is a map object.

In your case, to access the indexes, you can convert it to a list:

```
list(self.D)[i]
```

Or use unpacking to implicitly convert to a list (this may be more condensed, but remember that explicit is better than implicit):

```
[*self.D[i]]
```

Comment: Yes it is a map object. I was mistaken